# How to use a numeric prefix to repeat insertion of a digit?

Tags: prefix-argument

Suppose I want to type '222222' in emacs, how do I use the numeric prefix idiom to achieve this?  A naive guess would be 'C-u 6 2' but emacs interprets this as a numeric prefix of 62 and waits for the next command.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`C-u 6 C-u 2`

Documentation for `universal-argument` (emphasis mine):

> Begin a numeric argument for the following command.
>   Digits or minus sign following C-u make up the numeric argument.
>   **C-u following the digits or minus sign ends the argument.**
>   C-u without digits or minus sign provides 4 as argument.
>   Repeating C-u without digits or minus sign
>   multiplies the argument by 4 each time.
>   For some commands, just C-u by itself serves as a flag
>   which is different in effect from any particular numeric argument.
>   These commands include C-SPC and M-x start-kbd-macro.

You can find this documentation by typing `C-h k C-u` or `M-x describe-function RET universal-argument RET`.

Answer (score 4):

Your question title doesn't match the body text?

If you want to "repeat a number" (singular), nanny's answer has you covered.

If (as per the title) you want to "repeat a list of numbers", I would use a keyboard macro. e.g.:

<kbd><f3></kbd> `12345` <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd><f4></kbd>