# Insert multiple minus ('-') characters using the universal argument (C-u)

Tags: insert, keystrokes, prefix-argument

I was manually creating a table in my source code's multiline comments
and inserting horizontal separators using `-` and `=`. E.g. `C-u C-u C-u =` as expected and inserts 64 `=`s at the point. But `-` is used to provide negative arguments and does not work in the same way. `describe-function` for `universal-argument` does not address this.

So, is there a way of interpreting `-` as a "raw character" instead of part of a key chord?

Comment: While it does not work using `C-u`, it does work using the `C-0` to `C-9` characters, for 64 minus signs you can use `C-6 C-4 -` (Meta and Control can both be used together with digits to specify the universal argument.)

Comment: The `C-q` mechanism described in @shynur's answer is completely general and useful in many places: it's worth remembering. And because of that, I suspect that this is a duplicate question, but I haven't done a search to confirm yet.

Comment: After seeing @shynur's answer, I tried searching for "quoted insert", but nothing relevant came up.

Comment: @NickD : here the by you suggested existing duplicate: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7135/how-do-i-use-a-numeric-prefix-to-repeat-a-list-of-numbers

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not mention `C-q`, and the `C-u` method will not work e.g. with `C-u C-u -`: the `C-u` does not quote the `-`.  So it doesn't quite qualify as a duplicate in my book, but thanks for finding it. To some extent, all of these are corner cases, but they do tent to trip people up. Gilles' answer below is the most comprehensive  one I have seen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For example, `C-u C-u C-q -`.

You can `C-h k C-q` for more details.

Answer (score 4):

To type a minus sign with a numeric prefix argument, you can enter the number by typing the digits: `C-u 6 4 -` or `ESC 6 4 -` or `M-6 M-4 -` or `C-6 C-4 -` (or a few other combinations). This method doesn't let you abbreviate 4<sup>*n*</sup> by typing `C-u` <sup>n</sup> times.

Another method, which also works with a digit, is to use the `C-u` prefix, then enter the number, then another `C-u` and finally the character. For example `C-u 6 4 C-u -` inserts 64 minus signs, and `C-u 6 4 C-u 0` inserts 64 zeros. This method doesn't let you abbreviate 4<sup>*n*</sup> by typing `C-u` <sup>n</sup> times.

In most cases, an alternative way is to use `C-q` before the minus sign, e.g. `C-u C-u C-u C-q -` inserts 64 minus signs. However there are a few cases where this is different, such as Overwrite mode, where `C-q` inserts instead of overwriting. This method doesn't work for digits (except 8 and 9 when `read-quoted-char-radix` is the default octal): you would have to type the digit's octal code (or dec/hex if you've changed the radix), e.g. `C-u C-u C-q 6 0 RET` to insert `0000000000000000`.